# Get a list from an HttpContext.request object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Using jQuery I have serialized a form that and send it to the server in this format:

```
Object{
transactionID : "10779"
itemList : [{itemName:"ball", quantity: 5}, {itemName:"stuff", quantity:10}]
}
```

In a custom ASP.NET modelbinder, I do this:

```
HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

        foreach (var item in request.Form.Get("itemList"))
        {
            itemList.Add(new TransactionItemQuantity
            {
               name = item.itemName               
               quantity = item.quantity
            });
        }

        return new Transaction
        {
             transactionID = request.Form.Get("transactionTypeID"),
             itemList = itemList
        };
    }
```

However, the foreach loop does not work, as the IDE doesn't yet know that request.Form.Get("itemList") returns an array of objects. How do I make the above code work?

Comment: Are you deserializing the JSON string somewhere first?

Comment: No, it's used as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it like this you only get a char-array back from the request. You need to deserialize the content of `request.Form.Get("itemList")` into a List of your items, then you can loop through them.
Something like this:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(request.Form.Get("itemList"));
```

You are also creating a list of type `Item` first, but trying to add objects of type `TransactionItemQuantity` in the loop.

Edit: Added example